# socket.io - callback on server emit() not executing

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I just started using socket.io.js and am trying to get a function executed on the server as soon as I send a message to a client. My code is as follows,

server:

```
server.on('connection', onConnect);
var id = 0;
function onConnect(socket) {
    socket.emit('myMsg', {id: ++id}, function () {console.log('id callback on server');});
}
```

client:

```
iosocket.on('myMsg', function(data, callback) {
    console.log('id:', data.id, callback);
});
```

However I see that the callback function is displayed as 'undefined' on the client. From what I read on the docs I think this should work (https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Migrating-0.6-to-0.7+), so could someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I doubt it's the issue but it should be `function onConnect(socket) {`

Comment: the callback in (your) `iosocket.on(...)` only gets one argument, an object `data`, also `socket.emit(...)` only takes two arguments, an `id` and an object `data`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the `callback` must be a function. Try this:

```
iosocket.on('myMsg', function(data, callback) {
    console.log('id:', data.id);
    callback();
});
```

See the acknowledgement section of the following link for an example:
http://socket.io/#how-to-use

Comment: Isn't this from the client to server? I am looking for the other way around (via the emit)?

Comment: Yes it is. It doesn't seem to work the other way. Maybe you should use another event.

Answer (score 0):

if you would call callback as a function `callback()` on the client, it would activate your function on the server side, so it would console.log on your server.
if you just want to send a message from server to client, why make 2 callbacks? you can put it in data: `{id:id,something:else)`.
if you want to log that something on the client;

```
if(data.something) {
console.log(data.something); //outputs "else"
}
```